# Preparation of 6-bromo-1-hexanol

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, alcohols, halides

I am refluxing $\ce{HBr}$ with 1,6-hexanediol for 16 hours at $80\ ^\circ\mathrm{C}$ in toluene. How can I be sure that more than $90\,\%$ of the product is brominated only at one terminal? If the amount of double brominated product is in more than $10\,\%$ of the total yield, then the product mixture will be useless for me.

Comment: Would having unreacted 1,6-hexanediol be acceptable? If so, use it in excess.

Comment: @ringo the &deg; is not typeset well in math equations in mathjax, it's probably better to use `${}^\circ$`.

Comment: jerepierre what I am concerned about is the by product 1,6-dibromohexane which I can't allow to be there.

Answer (score 5):

In an article by Katharina C. Kress, Martin Kaller, Kirill V. Axenov, Stefan Tussetschläger, and Sabine Laschat, published in 
*Beilstein J. Org. Chem.*, **2012**, *8*, 371-378 ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.3762/bjoc.8.40)), this procedure is described. From the [Supporting Information](http://www.beilstein-journals.org/bjoc/content/supplementary/1860-5397-8-40-S1.pdf), I read that the authors obtained the product in 72% yield after

> column chromatography on silica gel (hexanes/EtOAc, 1:1)

I wouldn't be astonished if that's as good as it can get.